# AS3 using Sound.extract in a loop to analyse a soundfile

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, arrays, extract

From this AS3 code I expect 500 lines of trace outputs that contain "2048". But instead I get only some lines containing "2048". The rest of the traces print a "0" which shows me that the extract() method did not return any data.

Why is this the case? I would like to iterate through the soundfile with a specific amount of steps to extract 2048 bytes of the sound at the respective position. Extracting the entire soundfile at once would freeze the flashplayer for seconds and is therefore not a good solution for me

This behaviour can be found as long *steps* is smaller than *samplesInSound/2048*. The closer it comes to that value, the more lines with a "0" are printed compared to those with a 2048 in it.

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.load(new URLRequest("soundfile.mp3"));
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);

function soundLoaded(e:Event){
    var samplesInSound:Number = sound.length*44.1;
    var steps:int = 500;
    var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    for(var i=0; i<samplesInSound; i += Math.floor(samplesInSound/steps)){
        var extracted = sound.extract(byteArray, 2048, i);
        trace(i + ": " + extracted);
    }
}
```

I had the idea that the extracted part of the soundfile is cut out of the rest of the soundfile after extracting it (like at [Actionscript 3 - Sound.extract method empties sound object data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074297/actionscript-3-sound-extract-method-empties-sound-object-data)), so I tried out another for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<samplesInSound - steps * 2048; i += Math.floor(samplesInSound/steps) - 2048)
```

but this didn't work out either.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, so I'll write this answer with a disclaimer, let me know if it doesn't solve your problem.

Every call to sound.extract will just extract from where the previous call to sound.extract finished up, so you don't need to use the startPosition argument every time. That's why you were getting strange results, the call to sound.extract was already advancing through the sound:

```
sound.extract(byteArray, 2048) // advances 2048 samples into the sound
sound.extract(byteArray, 2048) // we are 2048 samples in, grab another 2048
sound.extract(byteArray, 2048) // we are 4096 samples in, grab another 2048, etc.
```

More importantly, the way you have it at the moment doesn't actually stop the Flash player freezing on a long sound, because you're doing it all in one loop anyway. Grabbing 500 * 2048 (1,024,000) steps in a loop is no better than just grabbing them all at once with sound.extract(byteArray, 1024000). If anything, it's slower. You need to give Flash time to 'breathe' inbetween the calls to sound.extract.

Here's a possible solution:

```
class SoundLoader
{
    public var sound:Sound;
    public var byteArray:ByteArray;
    public var samplesInSound:int;

    public function SoundLoader(sound:Sound)
    {
        this.sound = sound;
        samplesInSound = sound.length * 44.1;
        byteArray = new ByteArray();
    }

    // Returns "true" if the sound has finished extracting.
    public function extract(samplesToExtract:int):Boolean
    {
        var extracted:int = sound.extract(byteArray, samplesToExtract);

        return extracted < samplesToExtract;
    }
}

function soundLoaded(e:Event)
{
    soundLoader = new SoundLoader(sound);

    // 2048 is very low, you'll need to experiment with how much you can load at once without Flash hiccupping.

    if (soundLoader.extract(2048))
    {
        // A very short sound! soundLoader.byteArray contains the extracted sound, ready to use.
    }
    else
    {
        // add a timer that calls soundLoader.extract(2048) again.
        // keep repeating the timer until soundLoader.extract returns 'true' - then you can use soundLoader.byteArray.
        // the timer allows Flash to do other things inbetween, which avoids it freezing up.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my plan is to loop through the sound in bigger steps than the data I extract on each loop. What I would like to achive is for example this:

`sound.extract(byteArray, 2048, 0) // advances 2048 samples into the sound  
sound.extract(byteArray, 2048, 10000) // we are 10000 samples in, grab another 2048  
sound.extract(byteArray, 2048, 20000) // we are 20000 samples in, grab another 2048, etc.`  

I know about the freezing problem you mentioned. In the final code I will connect the loop either on the frames or, like in your example, on a timer.